# Please clarify what a sample is in statistics

Tags: statistics

Is a sample 
1) DATA from a SUBSET of a population?
 or
2) A SUBSET of a population?

I am not sure if its the Data or the actual Population that the data is derived from.

Answer (score 0):

A sample is a subset of the population. A data sample is the data collected from a subset of the population.